# Clustering strings inside strings?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, feature-extraction

I am not sure whether I formulated the question correctly. Basically, what I want to do is:

Let's suppose I have a list of 1000 strings which look like this:

cvzxcvzx**string**cvzcxvz

otortorotr**string**grptprt

vmvmvmeop**string2**vmrprp

vccermpqp**string2**rowerm

proororor**string3**potrprt

mprto2435**string3**famerpaer

etc.

I'd like to extract these reoccuring strings that occur on the list. What solution should I use? Does anyone know about algorithm that could do this?

Comment: How do you decide that "string", "string2" and "string3" are similar, but "string", "xstring" and "stringg", for example, are not?

Comment: As I understood it, string, string2 and string3 are placeholders; they are not necessarily similar.

Comment: By string similar I mean they are exactly the same, char by char. Additionally, there might be multiple pairs of exact substrings between the two strings.

Comment: No, the question is if there is another string that has "stringg" then if and how is it different from string2 or string3? The question is about defining EXACTLY what you want to do. Like is there a minimum length of strings you're looking to cluster? Is there a maximum length?

Comment: I've implemented longest common substring algorithm. It solved my problem but it's expensive computationally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! I have not encountered it before so here is a solution I just made up, inspired by the approach taken by the word2vec paper:

1. Define the pair-wise similarity based on the longest common substring (LCS), or the LCS normalized by the products of the string lengths. Cache this in a matrix for any pair of strings considered since it is expensive to calculate. Also consider approximations.
2. Find a Euclidean (hyperspherical, perhaps?) embedding that minimizes the error (Euclidean distance if using the ball, and the dot product if using the sphere). Assume random initialization, and use a gradient-based optimization method by taking the Jacobian of the error.
3. Now you have a Hilbert space embedding, so cluster using your algorithm of choice!

*Response to deleted comment asking how to cluster multiple substrings*: The bulk of the complexity lies in the first stage; the calculation of the LCS, so it depends on efficiently you do that. I've had luck with genetic algorithms. Anyway, what you'd do in this case is define a similarity *vector* rather than a scalar, whose elements are the k-longest pair-wise LCS; see [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/algorithm-find-the-first-k-longest-substrings-between-two-similar-strings) discussion for algorithms. Then I would define the error by the sum of the errors corresponding to each substring.

Something I did not address is how to choose the dimensionality of the embedding. The word2vec paper might provide some heuristics; see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/word2vec-toolkit/HRvNPIqe6mM) discussion. I recall they used pretty big spaces, on the order of a 1000 dimensions, but they were optimizing something more complicated, so I suggest you start at R^2 and work your way up. Of course, you will want to use a higher dimensionality for the multiple LCS case.